# Dokuwiki Proxy: Could not connect Permission denied (13)

Tags: proxy, dokuwiki

Dokuwiki responses with

```
Could not connect to <proxy> Permission denied (13)
```

when I try to use the [Wiki Upgrade](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:upgrade) Plugin. Also the [Extension Manager](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:extension) prints

```
The plugin repository could not be contacted. Make sure your server is
allowed to contact www.dokuwiki.org and check your proxy settings. [Retry]
```

I'm sure that the proxy settings are correct.

If I try to access www.dokuwiki.org with curl

```
curl https://download.dokuwiki.org -L
```

or wget

```
wget https://www.dokuwiki.org
--2016-11-15 15:13:08--  https://www.dokuwiki.org/
Connecting to <proxy:port>... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki# [following]
--2016-11-15 15:13:08--  https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki
Connecting to <proxy:port>... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

[ <=>            ] 25,784      --.-K/s   in 0.02s

2016-11-15 15:13:08 (1.38 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [25784]
```

in the console I have no problem.

I have no idea what I could do to find the problem.

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
- Dokuwiki Release 2016-06-26a "Elenor of Tsort"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Reason

[SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) is preventing the apache-httpd process to access the network. You have to allow the daemon access to use the Dokuwiki uprade features.

## The Fix

Check the settings with:

```
 getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network_connect
```

I got:

```
 httpd_can_network_connect --> off
 httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
 httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
```

With:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

you switch the network access for the **httpd process** on. (I had to install *policycoreutils-python* first, `rpm -qa | grep selinux` shows if you already have it.)

## Warning!

I am not familiar with SELinux (yet) and there may be side effects to this change that **compromise the security of your system**!

Found the solution with help from [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328174/apache-httpd-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-internet)

Answer (score 0):

You still can use 'Manual Install' tab to install plugins, it is not a real obstacle. Manual update procedure is not complicated as well.

1. Is doku running under the same user you are checking in console?
2. Have you checked proxy settings in Admin -> Configuration Settings -> DokuWiki\Network?

Comment: Thanks @Vlad! **2.** Yes, everything is correct. **1.** That seems to be the problem. Dokuwiki runs as user _apache_. And `sudo -H -u apache bash -c 'curl https://download.dokuwiki.org -L'` does not work! I will try to find the solution, but help is welcome!

Comment: For everyone with the same problem: I asked a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328174/user-apache-is-not-able-to-use-curl-connect-to-the-internet) and it seems we are on the right track to fix it.