# plugin repository could not be contacted (Dokuwiki)

Tags: dokuwiki

I am using Dokuwiki on my pc but suddenly getting this error. Now, i can't see the installed plugins and templates in *Extension Manager*(Admin). Just getting this error **The plugin repository could not be contacted. Make sure your server is allowed to contact www.dokuwiki.org and check your proxy settings. [Retry]**

I Installed it using xampp and dokuwiki(from youtube video)

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit).

Please help me regarding these problems, Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question so it only asks **one** question. You might also want to consider if this is actually on-topic here, because the question you ask does not seem to be about programming.

Comment: ok thanks. I am editing it to one question, The first question was asked by someone else here but he was a using linux user. I am asking it for windows because i really can't rectify that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding invisible installed plugins. I'm occasionally experiencing the similar issue but had no time to investigate. Try the following steps:

- Open Admin -> Extension manager.
- Uncheck 'updatable' checkbox.
- Switch to 'Installed templates' tab.
- Switch back to 'Installed plugins' tab.

If did not help try to play with the state of other checkboxes and switching to another tab and back. Please share your findings afterwards.

---

Regarding the error message check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612188/dokuwiki-proxy-could-not-connect-permission-denied-13).

- If it worked before and now you are experiencing sudden problems then check what was changed in your computer or network settings.
- Check proxy settings in Admin -> Configuration Settings -> DokuWiki\Network.
- Check if you can access `http://www.dokuwiki.org/lib/plugins/pluginrepo/api.php?cmd=ping` in your browser to decide whether you need to continue investigation on network or xampp side.
- You can always install plugins manually, you aren't going to do it every day.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it the way you told me about "invisible installed plugins" and it worked. but it's weird, i didn't unchecked anything, it got unchecked automatically might be while installing some plugin, no idea..

Comment: Regarding "error message" it's still there. I checked that question also, but i can't understand what is curl or wget,  how and where to use it ? in command prompt window ? 
- I had that error from start 
- In proxy settings in Admin -> Configuration Settings -> DokuWiki\Network,   my only these tabs are filled and all other are unchecked and empty :
**FTP server for safemode hack :** localhost, 
**FTP port for safemode hack :** 21,
**FTP user name for safemode hack :** user,
**FTP root directory for safemode hack :** /home/user/htdocs

Comment: This is my weblink for my dokuwiki (http://localhost/dokuwiki/doku.php?do=&id=start). I hope now you will understand better.

- I checked this link (http://www.dokuwiki.org/lib/plugins/pluginrepo/api.php?cmd=ping) but it shows the blank page with small "1" written on the top right corner.

Now i really don't know what to do, please guide me in simple language

Comment: @Abdul curl and wget are Linux commands, use your browser instead. Regarding proxy settings in Admin panel - if you are actually using proxy try to feel corresponding settings at the start of Network section. Small "1" is exactly what you need to see, so network is fine. I'd recommend to find someone to have their hands on your xampp+doku installation and carry out from there. Anyway it's not a big problem, just install plugins manually.

Comment: sorry i have never used Linux that's why i didn't knew those commands.  I understood. Just last question if you could ans, might be it's stupid/easy but i need to know - As, Dokuwiki is installed on my pc but I need to use Dokuwiki on the network (server) so that all people in this small company can use Dokuwiki from their PC's. How can i do that ? just need some hints. Thanks for your time.

Comment: just give them a link to your wiki like `http://localhost/dokuwiki/` with `localhost` replaced with your IP address or computer name.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from PHP <=5.6 to 7.0 running Detritus (and later) fixed this behavior.